# Checking that the propagator for Harmonic Oscillator satisfies Schroedinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator, propagator

I have the propagator for the harmonic oscillator.

$$K(x_f,x_0,t)=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2 \pi \hbar \sin{wt}}}\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{m\omega}{2 \sin{\omega t}}((x_0^2+x_f^2)\cos\omega t-2x_0x_f)-\frac{i\pi}{4} \right)$$

and

$$K(x_f,x_0,t)=<x_f |e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}t} |x_0 > $$

and the Schrodinger equation

$$\hat{H}\psi(\textbf{q},t)=i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(\textbf{q},t)
$$

This may seem silly but I just cannot see from my notes how you can the propagator satisfies this Schrodinger equation. I think it may come from some lack of understanding as to what the propagator means.

Comment: How did you derive the propagator?

Comment: Using the action of the Lagrangian, and a couple of clever tricks. This is stuff from lecture notes

Comment: For a general proof that path integrals reproduce the Schroedinger equation, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163075/

Comment: What you have to do is put your propagator where I had my general one. After probably pages and pages of math, you can verify it. I don't know of a more elegant method.

Comment: Voting to close as *unclear what you're asking* because nobody ever said a propagator should satisfy the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Read about greens functions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I think he means "satisfy" in the sense that the convolution of the propagator with an initial solution yields another solution.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I was looking more for an explicit way of evaluating the propagator on the Schrodinger equation than a more general explanation. Really I think I was just looking for a hint/first step of how I can "put" the propagator as shown in the question into the Schrodinger equation. I have a gut feeling that this should be a "simple" substitution.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Could you explain why "a propagator should (not) satisfy the SE"? This seems strange as it is pretty much the question I asked. I believe this is the problem that is stopping me from solving this question as I cannot see how to do this. I dont expect full solutions, nor is this work for credit.

Comment: The [propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) doesn't follow the Schroedinger equation, it obeys $\psi(x,t)=\int\psi(x',t')K(x,t;x't')dx'$. To check your propagator, you need to solve that integral.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you that was the explanation I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The propagator does satisfy the Schrodinger equation for *most* values of x and t...

The easiest way to show this is to let $\hbar=m=\omega=1$. Also, we can work with $\sqrt{2\pi}e^{i\pi/4}K\to K$ instead of $K$ to clean up the mess a little further. Further, let $x_f\to x$ and $x_0 \to 0$.

Then let:
$K=fe^{ig}$ with

$f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(t)}}$

and

$g=\frac{x^2\cos(t)}{2\sin{t}}$

And, since $m=\omega=1$, we want to show that:

$i\dot K = -\frac{1}{2}K''+\frac{x^2}{2}K$

Okay...

$\dot K=\frac{K}{2}\left({\frac{-\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}-i\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(t)}}\right)$

And...

$K''=K\left({i\frac{\cos}{\sin}-x^2\frac{\cos^2}{\sin^2}}\right)$

And... I'll leave the rest up to you. But, I assure you, you will find that:
$HK=i\dot K$

...of course, this is not actually, true since *actually*:
$HK=i\dot K+i\delta(x_f-x_0)\delta(t)$

And... I'll leave it up to you to reconcile this issue...

Comment: Sorry its not clear "for most values". I was expecting this to be some kind of "simple" substitution. Your step $\hbar=m=\omega=1$ is very useful.

Comment: Ah, I said "for most values" because K only *really* satisfies the schrodinger equation if the delta functions (see the very last equation) are zero. For example, you have problems at "t=0".